# Regex to match all domains and video ids from vimeo embed url

Tags: php, regex

I want to get multiple matches for dailymotion video url and video id from content below

```
<iframe style="clear: both; display: block;" 
src="//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x1a6ldm" 
height="315" width="420" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe style="clear: both; display: block;" 
src="//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x1a6k8x" 
height="315" width="420" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe style="clear: both; display: block;" 
src="//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x1a6k1i" 
height="315" width="420" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I tried all the codes below but no one work for me

```
preg_match_all ("/^.+dailymotion.com\/(video|embed\/video)\/([^_]+)[^#]*(#video=([^_&]+))?/", $content, $dailymotionmatches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

preg_match_all ("/http:\/\/www\.dailymotion\.com\/video\/([^_]+)/", $content , $dailymotionmatches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

preg_match_all ('/http:\/\/www\.dailymotion\.com\/video\/([^_]+)/', $content , $dailymotionmatches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

I also tried maximum questions on stackoverflow but did not find any solution for my case. I am very new to regular expressions.

I am testing it [**here**](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/3gN)

Comment: [parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net). extract link(s). test url with a regex. you might could also use [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url).

Comment: @tenub thank you for suggestion but I need regax!

Comment: `.*dailymotion\.com\/embed\/video\/[a-z0-9]+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex seems to work fine.

```
(www\.dailymotion.com\/embed\/video\/.*?)"
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/3gO

Example of usage based of your code:

```
preg_match_all ('(www\.dailymotion.com\/embed\/video\/.*?)"', $content, $dailymotionmatches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

**Update**

To grab the video id itself, use the following regex

```
(www\.dailymotion.com/embed/video/(.*?))"

preg_match_all ('(www\.dailymotion.com\/embed\/video\/.*?)"', $content, $dailymotionmatches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

And the video id's will be as an array in the result position 2